# Create multiple records in visual workflow using user input

Tags: visual-workflow, flow

I'm trying to create multiple records in visual workflow. The records will represent merchandise that's booked into warehouses. The page the user will see has some drop-downs and a large text field. Here he can select the warehouse and product name. In the large text box the serial numbers of the merchandise are entered.

The problem I'm trying to solve is that the input from the large text box has to be split split and looped through, creating a new record for every serial number. I have to parse the input (I guess in an action) and pass it back as a collection variable so I can loop.

My question is if this is possible at all? Or is visual workflow not the correct solution for this?

Comment: What is the logic on your split? Are the values in your input field comma separated, or do you have a regex that splits the serial numbers?

Comment: They are seperated by a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer to your question is "yes" because one can do most anything they want with a visual flow. Before they were called "flows" they were referred to as "interviews". This would be no different than looping an "interview process.

You'd probably probably find it helpful if you created a graphic or "mock up" of your page as well as a flow-chart (try [giffy](https://www.gliffy.com/)) of how you see your visual flow working.

The main question to ask yourself would be, what are the benefits of doing this in a flow vs using an in-line "list" where all records are submitted at once?

There's an example of the type of thing it sounds like you're looking to do in Rakesh Gupta'a Blog in article titled [Parsing Dynamic choice Multi-Select Picklist fields (Flow) – Reusable component](https://rakeshistom.wordpress.com/2015/02/04/parsing-dynamic-multi-select-picklist-fields-flow-reusable-component/). Other resources that you may find helpful are the [Power of Flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/en/events/webinars/power_of_flow) Webinar Series. The [Trailhead Process Builder Module](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/business_process_automation) also includes a section on Visual Workflow that would be worth your time going through.

Comment: This is good. Thanks, I'm off reading the links. Could you explain the in-line list  you mentioned? Not sure where to find that. Salesforce is still a bit unweildy for me.

Comment: Think of it as a "blank ledger" or "table" with each field name listed at the top and a submit button at the bottom. If you're new to Salesforce, I recommend you go through the following [Force.com Workbook](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook.meta/workbook/workshops_intro.htm), [Visualforce Workbook](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook_vf.meta/workbook_vf/) & the various Trailhead Modules which are great learning tools.